# How to lock changing orientation on device?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How to lock changing orientation on device?

I tried to use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

and this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

but nothing work when i use device. When app runs on simulator it works great.

simulator have iOS 6 and device 5.1.1. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight is not a BOOL, it's just a member of UIInterfaceOrientation enum. So you should be getting a compiler error anyway. What you want to do is return the result of the condition of UIInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, which test if the passed interfaceOrientation is what you need or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

The method returns YES or NO answering the question "should I rotate to this orientation: interfaceOrientation".
So you should return YES or NO - `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` is not a BOOL.
But you can use a comparison to return the BOOL like described above.

Comment: it works. But when the app starts orientation is portrait then, if i will rotate the device it changes and locks. But i want to my orientation will landscape on start, without rotating

Answer (score 0):

Open your project, select project file, goto summary section, and set desired interface orientation on 'Supported Interface Orientations' subsection. Good Luck!(for iOS 6.x)

Answer (score 0):

In your project .plist file add Supported interface orientations

and set the item to Landscape(right home button)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it only for 1 viewcontroller, you can do that either by

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

or by

```
//deprecated
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

If you want to set it for the whole app, make sure you change your Info.plist file and add `Supported Interface Orientations`

Answer (score 0):

You just add following lines in `.m` file

```
#define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 )
#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )
```

Then you have to add following methods in `.m` file

```
#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
   return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
#endif

#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Ifdefs happen at compile time, so this code is syntactically invalid. However, simply overriding both methods will work fine—iOS 5 will ignore `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` and iOS 6 will ignore `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.

Comment: Looking at it again, you're right that it "works"—but not the way you expect. It works because both `IOS_OLDER_THAN_6` and `IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6` are, in fact, defined by your code, and so both methods are compiled into your code. It would not function any differently if you removed the `#ifdef` and `#endif` lines.

Comment: I used those lines because of i created the build at that time in iOS5, So when i am trying to compile it shows some error that is why i have used those lines

Comment: If you don't want to build the `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` method unless you're building against the iOS 6 SDK, you want `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 60000`. What you're doing here will always build both methods. See http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/target-conditionals-and-availability/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 6 support include these two methods

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Also kindly note that this will work on xCode 4.5 +